# MySQL 8.0 SKIP LOCKED returns empty set when ordering by date

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to implement a concurrent update of a table in my app, and I found a strange MySQL behaviour. Looks like FOR UPDATE + LIMIT locks entire table in some cases instead of locking only those rows that were selected. Let's assume we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`  (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_created` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1, '2019-05-22 19:34:28');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2, '2019-05-22 19:34:46');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3, '2019-05-22 19:34:54');
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (4, '2019-05-22 19:35:01');
```

Now, let's concurrently retrieve the rows:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, date_created FROM test ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date_created        |
+----+---------------------+
|  4 | 2019-05-22 19:35:01 |
|  3 | 2019-05-22 19:34:54 |
+----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the same request in a concurrent transaction:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, date_created FROM test ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So that, the second concurrent transaction is unable to retrieve rows with id 1 and 2. In another case, when I order rows by 'id' field instead of 'date_created', it works just as I expected:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, date_created FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date_created        |
+----+---------------------+
|  4 | 2019-05-22 19:35:01 |
|  3 | 2019-05-22 19:34:54 |
+----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And a concurrent transaction:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, date_created FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date_created        |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2019-05-22 19:34:46 |
|  1 | 2019-05-22 19:34:28 |
+----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this a bug? Is there any workaround?

MySQL version: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour. The problem is that there is no index on the date_created column, so ordering by date_created to get two rows ends up locking all records. You can see this if you query the performance_schema.data_locks table from the same connection that executed the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED:

```
mysql> SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA AS 'Schema',
              OBJECT_NAME AS 'Table', INDEX_NAME AS 'Index',
              LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_MODE, LOCK_STATUS, LOCK_DATA
         FROM performance_schema.data_locks
         WHERE THREAD_ID = PS_CURRENT_THREAD_ID();
+--------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------------------+
| Schema | Table | Index   | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA              |
+--------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------------------+
| db1    | test  | NULL    | TABLE     | IX        | GRANTED     | NULL                   |
| db1    | test  | PRIMARY | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | supremum pseudo-record |
| db1    | test  | PRIMARY | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 1                      |
| db1    | test  | PRIMARY | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 2                      |
| db1    | test  | PRIMARY | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 3                      |
| db1    | test  | PRIMARY | RECORD    | X         | GRANTED     | 4                      |
+--------+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That is also why it works, when you order by the primary key: in that case only the rows required will be accessed and thus locked.

The solution to make it work for date_created as well is to add an index on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX (date_created);
```